# Calculating polynomials in Python?

Tags: python, polynomial-math

I really don't have code to post with this, since I'm pretty stuck on how to write it. I have to give a list of positive ints and an x value to replicate the following example:

```
>>> poly([1, 2, 1], 2)
9
>>> poly([1, 0, 1, 0, 1], 2)
21
>>> poly([1, 0, 1, 0, 1], 3)
91
```

The equation I have is `p(x) = a0 + a1x + a2x**2 + a3x**3 + ... + anx**n`, so an idea I had was checking the length of the list and making it so that it automatically determined how many calculations it had to do, then just replacing x with whatever value was outside the list. Unfortunately I don't know how to write that or where to start really.

Comment: Also I'm not sure why it only shows one * for a2x**2 and a3x**3, but it's supposed to be a2x^2 and a3x^3.

Comment: Are you trying to implement poly() function?

Comment: Yes. For the parameters I have l for the list and n for the int, but I'm stuck after that.

Comment: Are you doing this an some homework? If not, use `scipy` which has a plynomial class.

Comment: Yes, this was homework, so I couldn't use scipy or numpy or any other libraries like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def poly(a_list, x):
    ans = 0
    for n,a in enumerate(a_list):
        ans += a*x**n
    return ans
```

The enumerate function returns a tuple containing the index and value of each element in the list. So you can iterate easily through a list using "for index,value in enumerate(list)".

Comment: How does "for n,a in enumerate(a_list):" work? Is that just a shorter way of writing two for statements? Just to make sure I understand it as well as I can. The program works perfectly, thank you.

Comment: See the docs for [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate).

Comment: without enumerate you do `for n in range(len(a_list)): a = a_list[n]`

Comment: Oh alright, I see. Enumerate looks much simpler than that, and I think I understand it now. Thank you both for your solutions.

Comment: In a list, every element can be represented with a value and an index. Enumerate just returns both in the same 'for' statement.

Answer (score 2):

Even better if you have numpy:

```
>>> from numpy import polyval
>>> polyval([1, 2, 1], 2)
9
>>> polyval([1, 0, 1, 0, 1], 2)
21
```

I think you have to reverse the a_list first though. (it happens to work since a_list is palindromic )

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can implement `poly`:

```
def poly(l, x):
    sum = 0
    xp =1 
    for a in l:
        sum += a *xp #add next term
        xp = x* xp #xp is x^p
    return sum

print poly([1,2,1],2)
print poly([1,0,1,0,1],3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [itertools starmap](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap)

```
>>> from itertools import starmap
>>> def poly(a_list, x):
...     val = lambda p, a: a*x**p
...     return sum(starmap(val, enumerate(a_list)))
...
>>> poly([1, 2, 1], 2)
9
>>> poly([1, 0, 1, 0, 1], 2)
21
```

Comment: without `starmap`: return sum(map(lambda (n,a): a*x**n, enumerate(a_list) ))